# Запросы к mysql node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, запрос

Проблема в следующем

```sql
SELECT * FROM `rigs` INNER JOIN configs
```

отправляю такой запрос и получаю ответ записи из таблицы `rigs`, но мне надо получить как то и связанные записи... Как это реализуется в `Node.js`?

Comment: sequelize посмотри как это делает он я через него делал include все работало как надо

Comment: вообще такой запрос возвращает записи из обоих таблиц. причем, так как условия объединения не заданы, он вернет декартово произведение записей из первой таблицы на записи из второй.

Comment: Да, да выводит из обоих таблиц но вот так {"key": "value", "key2": "value2"}, но почему он не выводит так {"key": "value", "config": {"key2": "value2"}}, ведь key2, и value2 связанны с полем config...

Comment: Это **вы** об этом знаете. Но СУБД об этом в результатах не сообщает. Для неё `JOIN` просто сцепляет все возможные пары строк, подходящие по условию (если оно указано), без какой-либо вложенности.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from rigs as ri, configs as co where ri.rig_id = co.rig_id and rig_id = ?
```

Как вариант если у двух таблиц есть повторяющиеся значения можно сделать так..

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]